# Drupal path alias not found

Tags: drupal, drupal-6, drupal-path-aliases

Got a Drupal6 install, and I'm using a webform to collect some data.  The webform has a path alias set on the edit page as 'contact_us'.  The issue that I can't figure out (and hard to reproduce) is from time to time, some users end up on the page 'node/'.  Seems like that is a possible failure trying to find the alias or system path.

Any one seen this before?  Any suggestions on some places to look or to why this is happening?

Comment: Do you mean the users sometimes end up on 'node/' after submitting the form? Also, what does the webform normally do on submit?

Answer (score 1):

Do you have a module like path_redirect installed? Check to see that there is nothing trying to forward contact_us to node/.

Also, check that users have correct permission to access the form.

Also, 'domain.com/node' is the default homepage of Drupal. Are they submitting the form and being sent back to the homepage?

Answer (score 0):

In a site where more than one language are enabled, in some circumstances Drupal doesn't find the correct URL alias for the language currently set for the user, and returns the Drupal canonical URL instead.

You didn't report if the Drupal site is multilanguage, and if there is an alias for that URL also in another language; I cannot suggest more possibilities without knowing that.